# Python - Converter datatime do mysql

Tags: mysql, python, datetime

Estou a tentar comparar a data atual com a data do último registo da minha base de dados mysql:

```
sql2 = "SELECT created_at FROM tempaverage WHERE created_at IN (SELECT max(created_at) FROM tempaverage)"
  cursor.execute(sql2)
  current = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
  for (created_at) in cursor:
    diff = current-created_at
    print diff
```

Mas não devolve nada quando faço o `print diff` porque sai na excepção e se fizer o `print created_at` o valor é > `(datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 11, 45, 3),)`

De que forma posso comparar as datas?

Answer (score 1):

solucionei deixando de utilizar o: `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())`

passando então a usar: `datetime.datetime.now()`

```
  current = datetime.datetime.now()
  for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    created_at = row[0]
    diff = (current-created_at).seconds/60
```